# Menu : how to auto select first subitem

Tags: javascript, css, submenu

I need to reproduce the kind of menu we can find on forbes.com. I'm just interested in the logo item submenu. 
I'm almost done. I made the logo item menu, the first level menu with category names and the second level where are displayed article links from each category.

Up to now it's a full CSS menu set up on a basical way. When the user has its mouse on the logo, it just displays the first submenu level. I think I will need some JS because my goal is - like on forbes submenu - to display a mouseover effect on the first subitem  to allow the  second submenu level to be displayed in the same time. (it looks nicer)

Here is my code (simplified) :

```
<ul id="menu"><li>
<a href="#" >Mylogo</a>

<ul class="submenu1">

<li class="item1"><a href="#">item1</a>
<ul class="subemnu2">content</ul>
</li>

</ul>/*----submenu1-------*/
</li>/*-----li menu------*/
</ul>/*---- ul menu-------*/
```

Thanks for your help. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for your use case. You can do it with CSS3 animations:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

When a user hovers over the first subitem, you change its appearance (.submenu1:hover), and you can also trigger an animation to show the second level of menu items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I need a solution that works on all browsers. Basicly I need a JS that would say : on displaying .submenu1 > add mouse over effect on .item1 (to allow .submenu2 to be displayed in the same time.